# Ubuntu boots to orange screen after install

Tags: installation, boot, screen

I have a problem in which I boot my computer and everything works normally, I see a purple screen with various partitions to select such as my Windows 7 and Ubuntu partitions.  When I select the Ubuntu one, my computer boots to an orangish screen and plays what sounds like a drum sound once.  Then nothing happens and I have to reboot my computer because the computer is stuck at this orange screen.

My hardware is:

- Asus M5A97 motherboard
- AMD Phenom II 630 processor
- MSI r6670 MD1GD5 GPU
- TrendNet TEW-641PC Wireless Card

Comment: The drum sound is usually what one hears when Ubuntu reaches the login prompt.  Just a wild idea: when you hear the drum, even without seeing anything, what happens if you type your password and hit "Enter"?  Will it boot up to the Ubuntu desktop?